# Can a [C] question really be a dup of a [C++] question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

re: [modulus returning incorrect amount in c program when a negative number is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230875/modulus-returning-incorrect-amount-in-c-program-when-a-negative-number-is-entere)

I'm not saying my answer is the greatest, although it is much improved over its initial state. But the linked question appears very different, citing C++ standards. To apply a criterion from over on code-golf.SE (where I'm a much more active meta-participant), answers to the first are not valid for the second. Ergo, no dup.

I haven't searched, and there quite possibly is an existing C question that covers this, but the linked one here IMO ain't it.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers) is the highest profile C dup my brief search turned up.

So, what's the procedure for changing a dup link? Flag-a-mod? Meta-a-fuss?

Comment: Here's another one that looks like it could have been a good dup target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be.

Comment: Related to: [Should we discourage marking C and C++ questions as duplicates of each other and potential merges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195292/should-we-discourage-marking-c-and-c-questions-as-duplicates-of-each-other-and)

Comment: @RetoKoradi That does look like the best choice for a "canonical" question here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're completely correct. They are not duplicate questions, and the answer to the C++ question is a non-answer for the C question.

Simply vote to re-open the question, and leave a comment there explaining why the question is not a duplicate. Others who see that question will usually, from such a comment, also vote to re-open it, and after five votes, it will be open again.

Whether it should also be closed as a duplicate of a different question is only relevant after it's been re-opened. When a question is basically crap, and is closed for the wrong reason, most people here are happy to leave it closed. This question isn't crap, the reason why it is closed is incorrect, and I do frequently enough see questions re-opened for that alone.

Comment: Note while an irrelevant answer does fit the NAA flag, since moderator tools are broken, not showing the question when reviewing NAA flags, these will be marked declined.

Comment: @bjb568: Moderation isn't expected to employ expertise, but deciding whether an answer is relevant requires a subject-matter expert.

Comment: @bjb568 That's not relevant here. The answer to the C++ is a non-answer for the C question, but since it *wasn't* posted as an answer to the C question, there's no reason to flag it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Huh? Edits? Obsolete comment flags? Spam flags? Close votes?

Comment: @bjb568 "not an answer" is for stuff like "Have you tried...?" (should be a comment), "My breakfast tastes good" (delete), and other such things posted as answers.  No domain expertise needed.

Comment: @Izkata Like I said, NAAs requiring context will be declined.

Comment: @bjb568 My point was that moderator tools aren't broken, that's as designed...

Comment: @Izkata http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2310738#2310738

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I reopened this, then found a question that actually *was* tagged as [C], and re-closed it as a dupe of that question.

That's not quite the whole story though: that question had previously been closed as a dupe of a couple other questions, but neither of them was about C either (nor even about anything as closely related as C++) so I re-opened it and wrote an answer that actually gives the rules for C (and how they've changed over time, which they have).

For what little it may be worth: I chose the dupe I did over the "higher profile" one linked in the question here simply because it's substantially older. Perhaps one of those should be closed as a dupe of the other as well though.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the current 'duplicate' ([Modulus with a negative number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645897/modulus-with-a-negative-number)) is better than [Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be)?  The current duplicate was asked later, has a far lower score, and is itself closed as a duplicate of two other questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I simply didn't find that one, but you're right--it's a better choice as the canonical question (though the accepted answer could use a minor update to refer to C++11 instead of C++0x). The one I did find probably shouldn't really have been closed as a dupe of those other two though (it's tagged as [c], and they're not about C).

Comment: OK: I'm puzzled because it had been reopened so I reclosed it dup'd to 'Does either ANSI C or ISO C', and then three people including you reopened it and it was reclosed dup'd to 'Modulus with a negative number'.  I guess people didn't notice that the Meta Effect had already beaten them to the punch.